# Why is \patchcmd not working when also using \@ifclassloaded?

Tags: etoolbox

Why do these two MWEs produce different effects?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\aeloaded{Not loaded}
\def\aechanged{Not changed}
\patchcmd{\l@section}
         {#1\nobreak\hfil}
         {#1\nobreak 
          \xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
            \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{--}\mkern \@dotsep
            mu$}
          \hfil}
         {\def\aechanged{Yes}}
         {\def\aechanged{No}}%
\def\aeloaded{LOADED}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Did \verb=article.cls= load? & \aeloaded \\
Did \verb=\patchcmd=  work?   & \aechanged
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which generates:

[image]

But,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\aeloaded{Not loaded}
\def\aechanged{Not changed}
\@ifclassloaded{article}
  {\patchcmd{\l@section}
            {#1\nobreak\hfil}
            {#1\nobreak 
             \xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
               \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{--}\mkern \@dotsep
               mu$}
             \hfil}
            {\def\aechanged{Yes}}
            {\def\aechanged{No}}%
   \def\aeloaded{LOADED}
 }{\def\aeloaded{load FAILED}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Did \verb=article.cls= load? & \aeloaded \\
Did \verb=\patchcmd=  work?   & \aechanged
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

generates:

[image]

Comment: You can issue `\tracingpatches` in the preamble and `etoolbox` debugs the patching process to the log. Removing `#1` from the input will work in this case, `\nobreak\hfil` only appears once in the definition of `\l@section` anyway. Using a conditional in `\@ifclassloaded` and then using that conditional for `\patchcmd` does work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can let `etoolbox` debug the patching process by issuing `\tracingpatches` in the preamble. The log will contain useful (?) information why the patching failed.

With your code the log will contain:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 18
[debug] analyzing '\l@section'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] -- nested patching command and parameters in patch
[debug] -> the patching command seems to be nested in the
[debug]    argument to some other command
[debug] -> the patch text seems to contain # characters
[debug] -> either avoid nesting or use # characters with
[debug]    category code 12 in the patch text
[debug] -> simply doubling the # characters will not work
```

(The macro `\@ifclassloaded` will simply issue `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo`.)

If one would be using `` \catcode`\#=12 `` for the `\patchcmd` macro one would, of course, get:

```
[debug] -> the macro may have been defined under a category
[debug]    code regime different from the current one
```

Avoiding nesting seems easier (besides not using `#1` at all).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\aeloaded{Not loaded}
\def\aechanged{Not changed}
\tracingpatches
\@ifclassloaded{article}{\def\aeloaded{LOADED}\@tempswatrue}
                        {\def\aeloaded{load FAILED}\@tempswafalse}
\if@tempswa
  \patchcmd{\l@section}
           {#1\nobreak\hfil}
           {#1\nobreak 
            \xleaders\hbox{$\m@th
               \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{--}\mkern \@dotsep
               mu$}
             \hfil}
            {\def\aechanged{Yes}}
            {\def\aechanged{No}}%
\fi
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Did \verb=article.cls= load? & \aeloaded \\
Did \verb=\patchcmd=  work?   & \aechanged
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```